# Setting google analytics cross-domain tracking without the javascript

Tags: google-analytics, redirects, tracking

I sell a windows software through a third party company (FastSpring) and would like to track those sales with GA.

The problem is that all my "buy links" on my site ([www.easyjob.net](http://www.easyjob.net)) don't point directly to [www.fastspring.com](http://www.fastspring.com), so I can't implement the techniques described [here](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingSite.html#multipleDomains). Instead, they all point to a php file ([www.easyjob.net/buyNow.php](http://www.easyjob.net/buyNow.php)). I need this php in order to:

- Save affiliate cookies (if present)
- Decide to which fastspring.com url to send, depending on the location of the visitor (US visitors are sent a price in USD, EU visitors to a price in Euros).

All this is done without displaying any html (via a meta redirect) and without any interaction with the user.

How can I still send the necessary information to google when redirecting to the shopping cart at www.fastspring.com under this circumstances?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to track outbound links to get more accurate information on what links are going to your fastspring subscription.

http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55527
the link above explains it a bit.

Also, the Buynow.php script can be modified to track, if you put the google analytics code on there.  Put it there, and then a javascript redirect, would be a quick fix.

Comment: Link not working anymore :(

Comment: http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1136920

Comment: http://wptheming.com/2012/01/tracking-outbound-links-with-google-analytics/